# I have a mixed integer-string column: how can I change only the string?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with a column called `Text`. The rows of this column are all in the following format:

```
xxx - some sentence
```

where `xxx` is a random number. An example of what I have is:

```
      Text
100 - Hello World
200 - Bye World
300 - Good World
```

I want python to find only the string characters ("some sentence") and replace it to a value I specify. The method I am currently using is:

```
mapping = {"100 - Hello World":"100 - Bonjour Le Monde"}
df = df.replace({"Text":mapping})
```

which works fine for small datasets, but this dataset has 15k+ entries and multiple random numbers. I would rather not have to specify each number every time. How can I tell python to find the string and only translate the string?

Thank you very very much!

Comment: You want to translate the string to what? The same for each number? Or should change depeding on the associated number?

Comment: @Valentino I want to translate the string to French but I don't need to code that. I just need the function that finds the string and applies my mapping ONLY to the string. So for example, right now I have the entries: xxx - Hello, xxx - World, xxx - Smile.... where xxx is a irrelevant number. I want: xxx - Bonjour, xxx - Monde, xxx - Sourire....I can put the French words myself but I want to automate the process of changing each word to the French word (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `regex=True`

```
mapping = {"Hello World": "Bonjour Le Monde"}
df.replace({"Text":mapping}, regex=True)

                     Text
0  100 - Bonjour Le Monde
1         200 - Bye World
2        300 - Good World
```

Answer (score 0):

Being `xxx - some sentence` the value in your column, it is a whole string. What you need is to "translate" only the part of the string after the `-`.

To do this, you can use a custom function to do the job and use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to use it on the rows.

```
def translating(txt):
    print(txt)
    return input()

def substituting(x):
    spv = [el.strip() for el in x['Text'].split('-')]
    tl = translating(spv[1])
    return ' - '.join([spv[0], tl])

ddf = df.apply(substituting, axis=1)
print(ddf)
```

`translating` is the function which translates. Here I print the string and ask the user for a replacement at runtime just to give you an idea. If you have 15k rows you probably need to automatize this substitution mechanism with a dictionary or a translator tool.

Answer (score 0):

So you have your dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['100 - Hello World', '200 - Bye World', '300 - Good World']})
df

Text
0   100 - Hello World
1   200 - Bye World
2   300 - Good World
```

you can extract the two parts of the column with a regex :

```
df = df['Text'].str.extractall(r'([0-9]+) - (.*)')

        0       1
    match       
0   0   100     Hello World
1   0   200     Bye World
2   0   300     Good World
```

You create a dataframe with all your translations :

```
df_translate = pd.DataFrame({"en": ["Hello World", "Bye World", "Good World"], "fr": ["Bonjour Monde", "Au revoir le Monde", "Bon Monde"]})

    en              fr
0   Hello World     Bonjour Monde
1   Bye World       Au revoir le Monde
2   Good World      Bon Monde
```

You merge the two dataframes and create you column back :

```
pd_res = pd.merge(df, df_translate, left_on=1, right_on='en', how='left')
pd_res['res'] = pd_res[0] + ' - ' + pd_res['fr']

    0       1               en              fr                  res
0   100     Hello World     Hello World     Bonjour Monde       100 - Bonjour Monde
1   200     Bye World       Bye World       Au revoir le Monde  200 - Au revoir le Monde
2   300     Good World      Good World      Bon Monde           300 - Bon Monde
```